# Is the set of all subsequential limits always closed (for any topological space)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

In a metric space $X$, the collection of all subsequential limits of a sequence $\{p_n\}$ is closed (a few proofs can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672000/the-set-of-subsequential-limits-is-closed) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183268/zf-prove-the-set-of-all-subsequential-limits-of-a-sequence-in-a-metric-space)). I was wondering if such a result holds for *all* topological spaces. If so, how could one prove it? If not, what would be a counterexample?

Comment: Gabriel's answer demonstrates the result for any first-countable space, which makes sense as sequences interact with topology nicely in such spaces, and not necessarily so nicely outside of such spaces

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/521968) for an example to supplement Eric's example, with $A=\Bbb N\setminus\{1\}$ a countable set not containing its limit point $1$

Comment: If you had trouble understanding that example as I initially did, note that a sequence converging to $1$ must be unbounded, so there must be $a_{n_k}\gt 2^k$ for every $k$ in this sequence; then take $U=\Bbb N\setminus\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty a_{n_k}$ a neighbourhood of $1$ which contradicts convergence

Answer (score 2):

Take any space $X$ with a countable subset $A$ which has an accumulation point $x$ that is not a limit of any sequence in $A$.  (For instance, $X$ could be the [Arens-Fort space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arens%E2%80%93Fort_space).)  Now take a sequence $(x_n)$ which takes each value in $A$ infinitely many times.  The set of subsequential limits of $(x_n)$ then includes every element of $A$, but does not include $x$, and so is not closed.

Comment: I was searching for counterexamples along these lines... very nice. The key step is in taking a sequence attaining every value in $A$ infinitely many times; how can this be achieved? I have never seen such a construction

Comment: Just use a bijection $\mathbb{N}\to A\times\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Oh right, of course